# MSbuild exception before the debugger even step into the code

Tags: c#, msbuild

public class Builder
{
public Builder(string ip)
{
BuildClient(ip);
}

```
    private void BuildClient(string ip)
    {
   


        string projectName = "ArkerClient";
        string asemblyName = "clientASembly";
        string sRCEncrypted = "encryptedstring";


            string keyTemp = "fdstgfrt845e8t48";
        byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyTemp);

        string tempIV = "fdgi4g984398t49t";
        byte[] iV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tempIV);

        ProjectCollection projectCollection= new ProjectCollection();

        Project project;
        using (XmlReader xMLReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(csProj)))
        {
            project = projectCollection.LoadProject(xMLReader);
            xMLReader.Close();
        }

        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.Key = key;
            aes.IV = iV;

            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(sRCEncrypted);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                ICryptoTransform ICt = aes.CreateDecryptor();
                using (CryptoStream decryptStream = new CryptoStream(ms, ICt, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(decryptStream))
                    {
                        string data = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        string[] sRC = data.Split(',');

                        foreach (string sf in sRC)
                        {
                            string[] info = sf.Split('|');
                            ProjectItem csFileItem = project.AddItem("Compile", info[0])[0];
                            csFileItem.SetMetadataValue("Content", info[1]);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Client");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        project.FullPath= path;

        project.Build();
    }


}
```

System.IO.FileNotFoundException
HResult=0x80070002
Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Im trying to compile a program by using xml from a csproj file, and reading and decrypting source files adding them to the project, then building, but I get An error. In the constructor before the debugger steps into the method I get the error.

Comment: Did you add the NuGet packages for MSBuild to your project?